# Excel VBA If Zero or Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is fairly simple but I cannot seem to get this to work. I have a sheet that I copy into a workbook. Then loop the code through 30 columns looking for a value to copy into another sheet. However if the cell is zero or blank I want it to skip.

I have tried various versions of OR and have also tried IsEmpty(). However every time it hits a column that is blank, it copies the range into the other sheet and then carries on.

Is there a way to achieve this or statement?

```
    If EPRng.Value <> 0 Or EPRng.Value = "" Then

           *Code*

        Else

           *Code*

        End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code does not check "cell is zero or blank" it checks "not zero or blank"

Comment: `If EPRng.Value <> 0 And EPRng.Value <> "" Then`

Comment: Looks to me like your could use `SpecialCells(2)` if you want to set a `Range` object without empty cells. You can iterate through those cells now. Btw, you look for a value through iteration over 30 columns? This might be done a bit faster! Care to show some sample data and desired result?

Comment: Albeit the resolution should be in the above comments, another option would be to separate your multi-condition statement so you assess A) `not isempty()` then in the true condition assess if `<>0`.  If you were to loop and have an `or` situation, each would need to be assessed, which may not be necessary if the cell `isempty()`; food for thought about application of your code.

Comment: What range does `EPRng` actually represent?

Comment: Thanks Scott, I knew it was something simple! AND instead of OR